# Question about linearization of 2D matrix

Tags: c

So I converted a 2D matrix:

```
int m[10][10];
int i, j, tmp;
main ()
{
 // inlezen van de matrix
 for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 for (j=0; j<10; j++)
 m[i][j] = getint();
```

to a 1D:

```
int M[10*10];
int i, j, tmp;
int k, h;
main ()
{
 // inlezen van de matrix
 for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
 k = 10 * j + i;
 M[k] = getint();
 }
```

Lastly, we had to convert this code so it would be functional for our 1D array:

```
// voer complexe bewerking uit op de matrix
 for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 for (j=5; j<15; j++)
 m[i][j-5] += m[9-i][14-j];
 ... // Druk de matrix af
}
```

This was done in the book like this:

```
 for (i=0; i<10; i++)
 for (j=5; j<15; j++) {
 k = 10 * j + i - 50; // 10*(j-5) + i = 10*j + i - 50
 h = 149 - 10 * j - i // 10*(14-j) + (9-i) =
 // 140 - 10*j + 9 - i = 149 - 10*j - i
 M[k] += M[h];
 }
```

My solution however was,

```
for (k = 0; k < 100; k++)
M[k] += M[99-k]
```

I was wondering if my solution was also correct since what all the code above does, is add the symmetrical element. So that could be simplified with my formula, right?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doung with the one-dimensioanl array. For example what this assignment  m[i][j-5] += m[9-i][14-j]; means.

Comment: @Vlad From Moscow
It was commented as "execute complex mathematical operation". I assume it's just a random operation which happens to add the matrix-position which is symmetrical to another matrix-position. So for instance position [15] or [1] [4] would add [84] or [8][3]

Comment: It's a bit confusing that the one-dimensional array does not use the memory layout, where for `m[i][j]`, the row index is `i` and the column index is `j`, so that `k == 10*i + j`.

Comment: @MOehm, well there's two different layouts. Row-linearized which would be k = 10*i + j, but in this instance we used column-linearized, which imports column by column so k = 10*j + i

Comment: Yes, but C uses row-major layout, so that seems to be the more natural way to teach in my opinion. Seeing C code that does it the other way round is confusing.

Comment: I understand. We normally use the row layout, but I assume they wanted to add some variation in the exercises so they chose for column for this exercise. Anyways, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this code of the book, the index are the following:

```
[k] [h]
[99][0] [89][10] [79][20] [69][30] [59][40] [49][50] [39][60] [29][70] [19][80] [9][90] 
[98][1] [88][11] [78][21] [68][31] [58][41] [48][51] [38][61] [28][71] [18][81] [8][91] 
[97][2] [87][12] [77][22] [67][32] [57][42] [47][52] [37][62] [27][72] [17][82] [7][92] 
[96][3] [86][13] [76][23] [66][33] [56][43] [46][53] [36][63] [26][73] [16][83] [6][93] 
[95][4] [85][14] [75][24] [65][34] [55][44] [45][54] [35][64] [25][74] [15][84] [5][94] 
[94][5] [84][15] [74][25] [64][35] [54][45] [44][55] [34][65] [24][75] [14][85] [4][95] 
[93][6] [83][16] [73][26] [63][36] [53][46] [43][56] [33][66] [23][76] [13][86] [3][96] 
[92][7] [82][17] [72][27] [62][37] [52][47] [42][57] [32][67] [22][77] [12][87] [2][97] 
[91][8] [81][18] [71][28] [61][38] [51][48] [41][58] [31][68] [21][78] [11][88] [1][98] 
[90][9] [80][19] [70][29] [60][39] [50][49] [40][59] [30][69] [20][79] [10][89] [0][99]
```

So the answer is *YES*. To reduce the number of cycles, you could try:

```
for (i=0; i<50; i++){
            k = 50 - i; 
            h = i + 50; 
            tmp = M[k];
            M[k] += M[h];
            if (i != 0) M[h] += tmp; //No not sum twice [50]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.

It is simpler to see by taking a couple of intermediate transforms:

Starting from:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
for (j=5; j<15; j++) {
  k = 10 * j + i - 50; 
  h = 149 - 10 * j - i;
  M[k] += M[h];
}
```

Changing to the more usual range of j makes it simpler:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
for (j=0; j<10; j++) { //subtract 5 from j here
  k = 10 * j + i;      //so add 50 to compensate here
  h = 99 - 10 * j - i; //and subtract 50 to compensate here
  M[k] += M[h];
}
```

Then re-using k:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
for (j=0; j<10; j++) { 
  k = 10 * j + i;      
  h = 99 - k;          //substitute 10j+i => k
  M[k] += M[h];
}
```

Then it is simple to see that this is equivalent to

```
for (k=0; i<100; k++) { 
  M[k] += M[99-k];
}
```

You knew this already of course, but perhaps the above proves it more clearly.

Comment: Didn't even think of solving the equation to be honest, I just randomly took multiple values and realized my formula was equivalent. Thanks for confirming!